# Determine all entire functions $f$ with $f(z)\not\in (-\infty,0]$.

Tags: complex-analysis

This questions exists of two parts, I solved the first part.

(i) Determine all entire functions $f$ with $Real(f(z))>0$ for all $z$ and $f(0)=1$.

It is easy to see that $1/(1+f)$ is bounded and therefore constant. Therefore we get $f(z)=1$ for all $z$ as the only solution.

(ii) Determine all entire functions $f$ with $f(z)\not\in(-\infty,0]$ for all $z$ such that $f(0)=1$.

I noticed that this exactly is the area where the principal value Log(z) is defined, but I'm not sure that has anything to do with the question.

Comment: You could also take another function than $\operatorname{Log}$, but it has much to do with the question. (The intention was very likely to use a different function which has a branch defined on $\mathbb{C}\setminus (-\infty,0]$.)

Comment: The only functions I know that have branches there are logarithms and functions like $z\mapsto z^a$ for $0<a<1$ (which is, basically, again a logarithm).

Comment: @DanielFischer Could you maybe be a little more specific?

Comment: Actually, any $a\notin\mathbb{Z}$ gets you such a branch. You are right, these generally use the branch of the logarithm, but some - e.g. $\sqrt{z}$ - can also be defined without that if one wishes to do so. Anyway, my money goes to $\sqrt{z}$ being the intended function.

Comment: @DanielFischer But $\sqrt{f(z)}$ still is not bounded.

Comment: Look at part $(i)$.

Comment: @DanielFischer I'm sorry I still don't get it completely. We don't have $Real(\sqrt{f(z)})>0$ right? And I'm not sure what to do with $1/(1+\sqrt{f(z)})$

Comment: If we take the principal branch of the square root, we have $\operatorname{Re} \sqrt{f(z)} > 0$. If we take the other branch, it'd be $< 0$, but that's not much of a difference in principle.

Comment: Oh I see why we have $\Re \sqrt{f(z)}>0$ now, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Because ${\mathbb C}$ is simply connected, the fact that $f(z)$ is nonzero on ${\mathbb C}$ means there is a well defined entire $\sqrt{f(z)}$. The range condition you have for $f(z)$ implies that the range of $\sqrt{f(z)}$ doesn't intersect the imaginary axis. A few more steps and you can apply Liouville again....